# Stuck on 'You are about to visit: xxx.ngrok.io' and cannot visit my ngrok.io webpage

Tags: python, flask, ngrok

I am using flask-ngrok to hosting an index.html webpage for my machine learning model. Code to run the webpage:

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle
import numpy as np
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)

model = pickle.load(open('model_file.p', 'rb'))

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', "POST"])
def predict():
  input_values = [float(x) for x in request.form.values()]
  inp_features = [input_values]
  prediction = model.predict(inp_features)
  if prediction > 0.5:
    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Predicting a Recession in the US in the near future.')
  else:
    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Predicting no Recession in the US in the near future.')

app.run()
```

**This runs fine, however, when I click on the xxx.ngrok.io link, then it takes me to this warning page: **
[image: wr]

Even though I keep hitting on 'Visit Site', it never takes me to the site and just reloads the same warning page. I tried all browsers including edge. I even unblocked 3rd party cookies. Still can't avoid this.

Comment: You have two routes for `'/'`.  The second overrides the first.  Does this work if you run it on your local computer?

Answer (score 0):

PM from ngrok here. Try using the https url instead of http. We are investigating an issue where the cookie isn’t being set properly on http endpoints.

Comment: Any update on this. We are getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry for not following up here. We fixed this shortly after my last comment. If you're still having issues, let me know the exact error message.

Comment: @RussSavage: "You are about to visit equal-notable-sailfish.ngrok-free.app, served by 51.154.112.147. This website is served for free through ngrok.com. You should only visit this website if you trust whoever sent the link to you. (ERR_NGROK_6024)"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when serving/testing a Progressive Web App over NGROK. When the app tried to get `manifest.webmanifest` it would only get the NGROK warning page (which isn't valid JSON), causing an error. I managed to fix it by modifying my `link` tag in `index.html` thus:

```html
<link rel="manifest" type="application/json" href="/manifest.webmanifest" />
```

By specifying `type="application/json"`, the request seems to not trigger the warning message, and I get the result back as `application/manifest+json` (although sometimes I still get the error, it's not constantly like before). Not using NGROK for prod so this shouldn't be an issue when I move there.